# When does a slow MySQL query on a given connection affect other connections?

Tags: mysql, performance

I think I have a basic understanding of this, but am hoping that someone can give me more details as I am interested in learning more about database performance.

Lets say I have a very large database, with many millions of entries, the database supports many connections.  Doing simple queries on the database will be slow as there's so much data.  I'm trying to understand exactly when a query on a given connection starts to have a direct effect on the performance of queries running on other connections.

If one connection locks some elements, I understand that that will hold up queries running the other connections that need those elements .  For example doing:

```
SELECT FOR UPDATE
```

will lock what you are selecting.

What happens when you do something simple like:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM myTable
```

lets say we have a table with a billion rows so running the count is going to take some time (running on innodb).  Will it affect queries running on other connections?

What if you select a large amount of data using SELECT and JOIN, like:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable1 JOIN myTable2 ON myTable1.id = myTable2.id;
```

does having a join lock anything for other queries?

I'm finding it hard to know which queries will have a direct effect on the performance of queries running on other connections.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are different angles:

- Row locking: this shouldn't happen if you tune your architecture, so you should forget about it
- Real performances issues and bottleneck. In our case, collateral effects.

About this second point, the problem is mainly divided in 3 areas:

- Disk reads
- Memory usage (buffer)
- CPU usage.

About disk reads: the more data (in bytes) you will retrieve, the more the harddrive is going to be busy and slowdown any other activity using it. Reduce the size of selected rows to avoid disk overhead.

About memory usage: mysql manages an internal buffer, that can get stuck in some situations. I don't know enough about it to give you a proper answer, but I know this is definetly something you should keep an eye on.

About cpu usage: basically the cpu will get busy when it

- has to calculate (joins, preparing statements, arithmetics...)
- has to do all the peripheric stuff: moving bytes from disk to memory for instance.
  Optimize your queries to reduce cpu overhead. (sounds silly but, well, it always turns out to be the problem anyway...)

So, now when to know when there's a collateral effect? By profiling your hardware... 
How to profile?

- absolute profiling: use `SHOW INNODB STATUS` or `SHOW PROFILE` to get useful informations about main mysql harddrive, cpu and memory watches.
- relative profiling: use your favorite OS profiler. Under windows xp for instance, you can use the great `perfmon.exe` and watch for `PRIVATE BYTES` and `VIRTUAL BYTES` of the mysql process. I say relative, because afterall if a query is time consuming on your computer, it might not be on the NASA system...

Hope it helps, regards.

Comment: Thanks, that makes understanding the hardware side of things much clearer.  From the first angle, however, I still don't properly understand how I can be confident that a given query will or will not cause locking...

Comment: There no lock if you don't update nor delete (take care of CASCADE or TRIGGERS side effects) a given row within a transaction, or explicitly setup locks yourself by using the LOCK mysql command. A simple SELECT will NEVER lock a row. Also, take care of MYISAM engine which as far as I remember locks the whole table very easily!

Comment: Yep MyISAM does a table level lock on update/delete. InnoDB locks does row level locks if the where clause uses unique or primary keys in otherwise it may either do block level locks or table locks.

Answer (score 3):

Read queries are only affected by isolation levels of other queries. They themselves do not block the table **ever**.

Isolation levels are designated transactional safety modes. If *another* query that uses locking does not allow *dirty reads* your reads will be held until the *other* query finishes writing or unlocks.

[MVCC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiversion_concurrency_control) is a mechanism that allows databases to create a new version of the data when they need to update or delete. Which means that when you start a read on the current version of the data, it data won't get tainted by future updates/deletes.

When you start a write on current data despite the data being currently read by another process, you're in fact writing the new stuff somewhere else and marking them as the newest version. Which in the end means no blocking for the writing process (at least not because of the reading process).

Comment: Thanks, that makes a lot of sense, but how can one know that given query is a read.  What happens if you have a read query with a join like the one shown above that has a lot of work to do, it starts on connection A, then another query on connection B updates a row in the data that A is currently trying to select. What happens?  Does B wait for A? Does A have to stop and start again because B has made a change?  Any more information on this would be most helpful.

Answer (score 3):

This is a very general question, so giving a precise answer is difficult.

You can think of the database as a pool of shared resources; especially because the underlying hardware your database runs on has physical limits.  Most often the reason you see something like a select query that causes a performance impact on other queries it's because they're all competing for using those underlying physical resources like Disk IO or RAM access or CPU time and there isn't enough to go around.

So the actual results you wil see depend heavily on your database's physical hardware, and the configuration settings.

For instance in your select examples the variables might be:  Is the data the query needs already in RAM?  Can it look up the rows efficiently by an index?  If it does have to do IO, how many other queries are asking to read data from disk?  Are you using a secondary index and have to do multiple reads?  Is the database doing read-ahead to buffer other pages?  Is the query causing sequential or random io?  Are any updates holding locks on the data?  How much read IO can physical hardware support?

You would have to answer all those questions for all queries currently executing to know if they're going to affect performance of others queries.

This is why DBAs exist.  Busy databases are complex system, and it's all about the interaction of a great many different operations, all with thousands of possible variables affecting them.

So what you generally do is optimize the things you can control as well as you know how (hardware, mysql configuration, schema and indexes) then start measuring the system as it runs to understand what is actually going on.

So in your case, I would say that it's infinitely more helpful to focus on simply optimizing your queries individually.  The faster they execute, the less resources they are probably using and the less change they will impact others.  Then you learn to analyze the system.  Just look at one thing that's slow and ask "why is this slow?"  Then fix it.  That's the optimization process.

However, in the first case you wrote with SELECT ... FOR UPDATE explicit locks can and will be big performance issues.  Be careful with those.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, can you give me any advice on how to know if a SQL query will cause blocking issue.  How did you instantly know that the SELECT ... FOR UPDATE would cause problems?  Which other SQL commands cause similar issues?

Comment: SELECT FOR UPDATE locks rows for InnoDB, or locks the table for MyISAM. It is used in transactions to acqure locks on data that you will process and eventually update. It may also lock rows that do not fit the where clause, I didn't quite understand why they were also locked (when I read this) but it's something to do with them being a partial candidate in that where clause and not being released.